# Find Longest Line in a .txt File and fill all Lines to that Length with 'blank Spaces'?

Tags: bash, text, macos, shell

How can I find the longest line in a .txt file and then fill all other lines at their end to that length with blank spaces?

My guess is this is easy to answer. I know very little about using the awk, paste command
and such. Maybe someone can help me out. Thanks!

A little more specific... so far I can do the following. This would get the longest Line from a .txt File:

```
awk '{ if (length($0) > max) {max = length($0); maxline = $0} } END { print maxline }' in.txt
```

This fills the lines with blank spaces (till 50):

```
awk  'length <= 50 { printf "%-50s\n",$0 }' in.txt > out.txt
```

I just don't know to pass the value from one line to the other.

Why am I asking this? I want to merge two .txt files using the paste command. Text B will be positioned to the right of Text A. Lines in Text A will have different lengths. So if there are not enough blank spaces the layout isn't right.

Comment: as always, please post what you have tried so far - troubleshoot yes, do your homework, no.

Answer (score 3):

This is all you need:

```
pr  -W 80 -mtT file1 file2
```

Or, more verbosely:

```
pr --page-width=80 --merge --omit-header --omit-pagination file1 file2
```

Vary the number to change the layout of the result.

Comment: @noexpert: In what way do they not work? If you can be more specific I can be more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

here's how one way to it with just awk.

```
$ more file
jlsf
slf
asdfasfs
sd

$ awk 'FNR==NR{t=(length>=t)?length:t;next}length<t{for(o=1;o<=t-length;o++)s=s "|";$0=$0s;s=""}1' file file
jlsf||||
slf|||||
asdfasfs
sd||||||
```

Change "|" to spaces as desired.

Comment: This is what I was Looking For. And it works like a Charm.
Many Thanks to You and Everyone who took a little Time to help out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wc` to count the number of characters in a line.  Measure all lines in the file to find the longest length.  For all other files, (max length - line length) gives you the number of space characters to print at the end of the line (which you can do with `printf`).

**Update:**
Is using `awk` a requirement?  If not, try this:

```
# Measure the longest line in the file
maxlen=`wc -L filename.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

# Pad each line to $maxlen characters
while read line
do
    printf "%-${maxlen}s\n" "$line" >> outfile.txt
done < filename.txt
```

**Edit #2:**
If you don't have the `-L` option to `wc`, you can calculate the length of the longest line using the following loop:

```
maxlen=0
while read line
do
    thislen=`echo $line | wc -c`
    [ $[$thislen>$maxlen] ] && maxlen=$thislen
done < filename.txt
```

The ending value of `$maxlen` will be the length of the longest line.

Comment: Yes, stumbled over that already also. Thanks. See above I tried to be more specific.

Comment: Unfortunately that Option '-L' is not given in wc on mac os x
Also not 'wc --max-line-length'

Answer (score 2):

`wc -L` or `wc --max-line-length` computes and displays the length of the longest line in the input (may not be available on all versions of `wc`).

---

With the max line length in some variable (say, `$max`), run

```
while read line
do
    printf "%-${max}s\n" $line
done < in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Yes, stumbled over that already. Thanks. See above I tried to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If 'shell scripting' can include Python scripts, something like this:

```
maxLen = 0
infile = open("file.txt", 'r')
outfile = open("out.txt", 'w')
for line in infile:
    if len(line)>maxLen: maxLen = len(line)
infile.seek(0)
for line in infile:
    rawline = line.strip('\r\n')
    out.write (rawline + ''.join([' ' for i in range(maxLen-len(rawline))]) + "\n")
infile.close ()
outfile.close ()
```

Fixing any off-by-one errors is left as an exercise for the reader! :-)

Comment: Do you need a rewind operation between the two for loops?

Comment: Could you exploit the Python analogue of 'printf("%.80s\n", line)' to do the blank padding, where the 80 is the calculated maximum line length?  You'd create the format string after the first pass through the file.

Comment: @Jon - yes, fixed :-) 
You could probably do something like the clever format string, it would be certainly be more concise!

Comment: hopefully, I dont need python, that would be a whole new Area to me... :(

Answer (score 1):

You could combine your original ideas:

`awk '{ if (length($0) > max){max = length($0)} } END { print max }' in.txt`

`awk 'length <= 50 { printf "%-50s\n",$0 }' in.txt`

Use a shell variable to pass the result from one script to another, using awk's `-v` argument parsing

`MAX=$(awk '{ if (length($0) > max){max = length($0)} } END { print max }' in.txt)`

`awk -v max=$MAX 'length <= max { printf "%-"max"sX\n",$0 }' in.txt`

OR you could replace the hard-coded `50` with shell `$()` command substitution to create this ugly one-line beast:

`awk -v max=$(awk '{ if (length($0) > max){max = length($0)} } END { print max }' in.txt) 'length <= max { printf "%-"max"s\n",$0 }' in.txt`